# forEach() Method Throwing an Error

Tags: javascript, foreach

I have a forEach method to loop over some divs and return the said divs.  When i use the following code it throws an error and says forEach is not a function.

When I console log myDiv it does return values, so I know the var myDiv is working and returning an array-like object, but the forEach method throws the error.

JAVASCRIPT

```
var mydiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

mydiv.forEach(function(item, index) {
 console.log(item, index);
});
```

CSS

```
 body {display: flex;}
.box {width: 100px; height: 100px; background: red; margin: 0 10px;}
```

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: `forEach` only works for arrays, not array-like objects.

Comment: The `.getElementsByTagName()` does not return an array. *Some* browsers implement the array prototype functions on NodeList objects, but not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `HTML5`'s selector API `querySelectorAll()` instead of `getElementsByTagName()`.

`document.querySelectorAll('div');`

```js
var mydiv = document.querySelectorAll('div');

mydiv.forEach(function(item, index) {
 console.log(item, index);
});
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

Comment: This will not help. That API also returns a NodeList.

Comment: @Pointy, would you check my answer as I think it is working as expected with `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: @Pointy but [**NodeLists**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Methods) do have a function called `forEach`.

Comment: not supported in some older browsers https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach#Browser_Compatibility and as a side note, `querySelectorAll` is still a lot slower than `getElementsByTagName` https://jsperf.com/queryselectorall-vs-getelementsbytagname

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir according to MDN it's not supported in any IE version (but it is in newer Edge).

Comment: @Mamun it may work for you in your browser, but if you're using IE11 or something older, or an older Android browser, it won't.

Comment: @Pointy `NodeList` does have a `forEach` method, `HTMLCollection` does not! This is one way to help OP's issue.

Comment: @Slai I believe this browser supports issue and performance have never been OP's concerns. This solution should work in whatever OP's browser is using ([flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and [querySelectorAll](https://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll))

Comment: @choz In IE9? IE10? But your point is valid — `.getElementsByTagName()` returns an `HTMLCollection`, while `QuerySelectorAll` returns a NodeList.

Comment: @Pointy Nah, wont work on them. But seriously, should we even consider to answer in SO forum by considering it also has to support IE9 and IE10? At least this should work on OPs browser.

Comment: @choz sadly a lot of people are stuck with supporting legacy IE browsers, particularly in the world of Enterprise web applications.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, and I am one of those people!

Comment: @choz My comment is more towards anyone else considering the answer. It doesn't really matter what we and OP are using, as unfortunately some users are still limited to IE only. Alternative is to use transpiler to convert the code - left side works in new browsers and right side in older browsers: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=for%20(var%20item%20of%20document.getElementsByTagName('div'))%20console.log(item)